# Labeling duplicates in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

Say I have a list of names in python, such as the following:

`names = ['Alice','Bob','Carl','Dave','Bob','Earl','Carl','Frank','Carl']`

Now, I want to get rid of the fact that there are duplicate names in this list, but I don't want to remove them. Instead, for each name that appears more than once in this list, I want to append a suffix to that name, where the suffix is the n-th time the name has appeared, while preserving the order of the list. Since there are 3 Carls in the list, I want to be able to refer to them as Carl_1, Carl_2, and Carl_3 respectively. So in this case the desired output is as follows:

`names = ['Alice','Bob_1','Carl_1','Dave','Bob_2','Earl','Carl_2','Frank','Carl_3']`

I can do this by looping through the list and modifying each name if it needs to be modified, for example with something like the following code.

```
def mark_duplicates(name_list):
    output = []
    duplicates = {}
    for name in name_list:
        if name_list.count(name) = 1:
            output.append(name)
        else:
            if name in duplicates:
                duplicates['name'] += 1
            else:
                duplicates['name'] = 1
            output.append(name + "_" + str(duplicates['name']))
    return output
```

However this is a lot of work and a lot of lines of code for something that I suspect shouldn't be very hard to do. Is there a simpler way to accomplish what I want to do? For example, using something such as list comprehension or a package like itertools or something?

Comment: I don't think there is a reasonable one-liner, if that is what you are looking for. Anyway, what do you expect to get if input is `['Alice', 'Alice', 'Alice_1', 'Alice_2']`?

Comment: Theoretically that type of input will never happen. If it does, however, then I guess I'd be screwed because our resulting list would be `['Alice_1','Alice_2','Alice_1','Alice_2']`.

Comment: The reason I asked is because you maybe wanted result to be `['Alice_1','Alice_2','Alice_3','Alice_4']` (I don't know what it's for). That would require a different algorihm altogether.

Comment: I don't really have a good answer for how the problem you raised should be handled actually.

The underscore deliminator was chosen because I didn't expect it to appear in any of the "names". Really I could have chosen a strange separator that would never appear like 'Alice[__|]1', but I assumed that underscore wouldn't appear in a normal name. If I need to change it I can always modify the separator into some other string.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`collections.Counter` can help cut down on the bookkeeping a bit:

```
In [106]: out = []

In [107]: fullcount = Counter(names)

In [108]: nc = Counter()

In [109]: for n in names:
     ...:     nc[n] += 1
     ...:     out.append(n if fullcount[n] == 1 else '{}_{}'.format(n, nc[n]))
     ...:

In [110]: out
Out[110]:
['Alice', 'Bob_1', 'Carl_1', 'Dave', 'Bob_2', 'Earl', 'Carl_2', 'Frank', 'Carl_3']
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code should do what you're looking for and uses comprehensions:

```
def get_duplicates(names):
    counts = { k: 0 for k in names }
    output = []
    for name in names:
        if count[name] == 0:
            output.append(name)
            counts[name] += 1
        else:
            output.append("{}_{}".format(name, counts[name]))
            counts[name] += 1
    return output
```

**Update:** I fixed the code in my answer to properly return what OP was looking for. Not the best way, but it doesn't require use of another library and uses 1 `dict` comprehension and 1 loop.

Comment: `counts[name]` needs to be wrapped in `str()`

Comment: I believe that should be fixed now that I switched to `format`.

Comment: It puts a count on items that appear only once though.

Comment: `return ['_'.join([name, str(counts[name])]) if counts[name] > 1 else name for name in names]` fixed. List comprehension `if/else` format is `[this if condition else that for iterator]`

Comment: @FranciscoCouzo good catch. This should also be taken into account now.

Comment: This one puts the same number after each of the names (e.g., the three Carls in the example come back as `['Carl_2', 'Carl_2', 'Carl_2']` rather than `['Carl_1', 'Carl_2', 'Carl_3']`).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the initial order, you could think of this this way:

- Count the number of times each name appears
- Generate a list where, if the name only appears once, we don't add anything, but if it appears more than once, it adds `_1`, `_2`... to the second and subsequent appearances.

This means, you could use a [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to get the job done:

```
import collections

names = ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Carl', 'Dave', 'Bob', 'Earl', 'Carl', 'Frank', 'Carl']

counter = collections.Counter(names)
print("Counter: %s" % counter)

result = []
for name, counts in counter.iteritems():
    result.append(name)
    for i in range(1, counts):
        result.append("%s_%d" % (name, i))
print(result)
```

Which outputs:

```
Counter: Counter({'Carl': 3, 'Bob': 2, 'Earl': 1, 'Frank': 1, 'Alice': 1, 'Dave': 1})
['Earl', 'Frank', 'Alice', 'Dave', 'Carl', 'Carl_1', 'Carl_2', 'Bob', 'Bob_1']
```

If you wanted to add the `_1`, `_2` suffix to *all* the names that have more than one occurrence in the list, but leave the names that only occur once untouched, you could do:

```
import collections

names = ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Carl', 'Dave', 'Bob', 'Earl', 'Carl', 'Frank', 'Carl']

counter = collections.Counter(names)
print("Counter: %s" % counter)

result = []
for name, counts in counter.iteritems():
    if counts == 1:
        result.append(name)
    else:
        for i in range(counts):
            result.append("%s_%d" % (name, i + 1))
print(result)
```

Which outputs:

```
Counter: Counter({'Carl': 3, 'Bob': 2, 'Earl': 1, 'Frank': 1, 'Alice': 1, 'Dave': 1})
['Earl', 'Frank', 'Alice', 'Dave', 'Carl_1', 'Carl_2', 'Carl_3', 'Bob_1', 'Bob_2']
```

Answer (score 0):

If `['Alice', 'Bob', 'Carl', 'Dave', 'Bob_2', 'Earl', 'Carl_2', 'Frank', 'Carl_3']` is acceptable output (the first person not having a `_1` added on) then I would suggest the following:

```
counts = {}
def append(name):
    try:
        counts[name] += 1
        return True
    except:
        counts[name] = 1
        return False

def get_duplicates():
    return ['_'.join([name, str(counts[name])]) if append(name) else name for name in names]
```

The benefit to this approach is I only go through `names` a single time, which is why I cannot know ahead of time whether more will appear.

---

To meet the spec, I can further modify append:

```
def append(name):
    if names.count(name) != 1:
        try:
            counts[name] += 1
        except:
            counts[name] = 1
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

which will give the expected result:

```
['Alice', 'Bob_1', 'Carl_1', 'Dave', 'Bob_2', 'Earl', 'Carl_2', 'Frank', 'Carl_3']
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution which uses `enumerate`:

```
>>> names = ['Alice','Bob','Carl','Dave','Bob','Earl','Carl','Frank','Carl']
>>> processed = []
>>> for n in names:
...     if n not in processed:
...         indices = [i for i,name in enumerate(names) if name == n]
...         if len(indices) > 1:
...             suffix = 1
...             for i in indices:
...                 names[i] = "{}_{}".format(names[i], suffix)
...                 suffix += 1
...     if n.split('_')[0] not in processed:
...         processed.append(n)
...
>>>
>>> names
['Alice', 'Bob_1', 'Carl_1', 'Dave', 'Bob_2', 'Earl', 'Carl_2', 'Frank', 'Carl_3']
```